# Unknown column 'month' in 'field list' value not understood in jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

In my database having month field, but I get an exception unknown field list month.

**MySQL Query**

```
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(
    "insert into `horizontalemp`.`register`(" +
        "empid,basicsalary,da,hra,netpay,pf," +
        "insurance,deduction,grosspay,month,name" +
    ") values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
);
```

Comment: z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,z9,z10 it my arraylist value

Comment: Please show output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE horizontalemp.register`.

Comment: @eggyal i try to insert the arraylist(z1..z11) value in the register table..

Comment: `MONTH` is a reserved word, you need to quote it.

Comment: @eggyal thank u alot my table name is incorrect,now my value is inserted sucessfully.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: No, [it isn't](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).